# Inject parameter into Service Symfony 3.3

Tags: symfony

I have a service which injects string values from my parameters.yml.

I declared the service like so:

```
parameters:
    url: '%cms_url%'
    client_id: '%cms_client_id%'
    client_secret: '%cms_client_secret%'

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository}'

    api:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Api
        arguments: ['@session', '%cms_url%']
        autowire: false

    access_token_generator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\AccessTokenGenerator    
        arguments: [cms_url, cms_client_id, cms_client_secret]
        autowire: false
```

When I ran the app it AccessTokenGenerator throws an error saying:

> Cannot autowire service argument $apiUrl must have typehint or given
>   value directly.

This is my AccessTokenGenrator class:

```
class AccessTokenGenerator
{
    private $apiUrl;

    private $clientId;
    private $clientSecret;

    public function __construct(string $apiUrl, string $clientId, string $clientSecret)
    {
        $this->apiUrl = $apiUrl;
        $this->clientId = $clientId;
        $this->clientSecret = $clientSecret;
    }

    public function generateAccessToken(string $username, string $password) : ?AccessToken
    {
        $queryParams = [
            'client_id'     => $this->clientId,
            'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
            'grant_type'    => 'password',
            'username'      => $username,
            'password'      => $password
        ];
        $requestUrl = $this->apiUrl . '/oauth/v2/token?' . http_build_query($queryParams);

        $client = new Client();
        $request = new Request('GET', $requestUrl);
        $response = $client->send($request);

        $contents = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

        if (isset($contents['access_token'])) {
            $accessToken = new AccessToken();
            $accessToken->setAccessToken($contents['access_token']);
            $accessToken->setExpiresIn($contents['expires_in']);
            $accessToken->setTokenType($contents['token_type']);
            $accessToken->setScope($contents['scope']);
            $accessToken->setRefreshToken($contents['refresh_token']);

            return $accessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know why it proceeds to autowiring even my configuration is set to false.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know why autowiring still is active maybe a cache issue? But you don't need to turn it off at all. You can just pass the parameter manually as named argument. Look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#manually-wiring-arguments

Comment: Because you have marked this question as resolved, we are curious to know how you have resolved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not autowire scalar parameter just object

see documentation

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#fixing-non-autowireable-arguments

Comment: Thanks, Just missed that part of the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Good comment, but it does not answer the question. It is a comment, and not an answer

Comment: If he need to declare a service with a scalar argument,  it should be declared at autowire false ... No ?

Comment: I don't understand you last comment. If you set autowire to false, you lose the interest of autowiring ...

Comment: this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

@Arno is right you can autowire a scalar if you specify exaclty the name of paramaters.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-parameters

sorry i haven't see it part before.

Answer (score 2):

The `AppBundle\Security\AccessTokenGenerator` service is automatically loaded with `autowire: true` by this declaration :

```
AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
```

You can override any service that's imported by using its id (class name) below

```
AppBundle\Security\AccessTokenGenerator:
    arguments: ['%cms_url%', '%cms_client_id%', '%cms_client_secret%']
```

Warning, you have forgottent the percentage '%' for arguments.
If you need a `access_token_generator` service, you can make an alias :

```
access_token_generator: '@AppBundle\Security\AccessTokenGenerator'
```

Final file could be :

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository}'

    api: '@AppBundle\Service\Api'
    AppBundle\Service\Api:
        arguments: {$apiUrl: '%cms_url%'}

    access_token_generator: '@AppBundle\Security\AccessTokenGenerator'
    AppBundle\Security\AccessTokenGenerator:
        arguments: ['%cms_url%', '%cms_client_id%', '%cms_client_secret%']
```

[Documentation : manually wiring arguments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#manually-wiring-arguments)

[Documentation : explicitly configuring services and arguments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#explicitly-configuring-services-and-arguments)